# C# - How to iterate through a list of lists

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sqlite, sqlite-net

I have a class --

```
public class AccountNumber
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber_RecordID { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber_SegmentLength { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber_Number { get; set; }

}
```

I'm using LINQ to XML to get the list --

```
List<AccountNumber> accNum = 
 (from p in xmlDocument.Descendants("AccountNumber")                                      
  select new AccountNumber
  {
      AccountNumber_RecordID = (string)p.Element("RecordID").Value,
      AccountNumber_SegmentLength = (string)p.Element("SegmentLength").Value,
      AccountNumber_Number = (string)p.Element("Number").Value
  }).ToList();
```

I have a SQLite db created from the class AccountNumber. I want to use the entire list in an update statement. But how do i iterate through the list?

I want something like this, but not sure how to achieve it.

```
foreach accNum
        {
               db.Insert(accNum); 
        }
```

Comment: You don't have a list of lists.  Are you asking for a basic `foreach` loop or for an `Insert` method that takes a list?

Comment: if i use foreach (var in accNum)
        {
               some code
        }  then each item in the list accNum will be parsed. Is there a way I can pass the entire list

Comment: You're close... `foreach (var x in accNum)`.

Comment: @smaya: You can pass the entire list to any function that accepts a list, just like any other parameter.

Comment: `AccountNumber` is not a list. It's a class. Is that what you meant by "list of lists"?

Answer (score 3):

Close with the foreach, it would be as follows:

```
    foreach (var acc in accNum)
    {
        db.Add(acc); 
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Not forgetting to save changes.

Comment: But will this fetch me the entire list or only one element at a time? In the first instance, wont acc hold only AccountNumber_RecordID??

Comment: @smaya Instead of sitting there scaring yourself with ghost stories about what the code *might* do, run the code and see what it does.

Comment: `accNum` is already a List (you called ToList() on the query) - The code in this answer simply iterates that list (already retrieved from the db)

Comment: @smaya: You're completely misunderstanding lists and objects.  `foreach` gives you each object in the list.